# What would happen if our galaxy and an identical anti-matter galaxy annihilated each other?

Tags: universe, antimatter, galaxies, matter

What would happen if every bit of matter in our galaxy annihilated with an anti-matter equivalent at the same time? Such as that stars completely annihilated with identical antimatter stars, planets with identical anti-matter planets, dust with anti-matter dust and so on, leaving no matter or antimatter behind. What kind of damage would that create? Would just our galaxy and our satellite galaxies be destroyed? Or would the annihilation event take out a chunk of the universe? How visible would it be from far away? What would it look like? What ramifications would this event create?

Comment: Physicists do not believe that there are antimatter galaxies, so this is a completely fictional scenario and they are generally [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @G. Smith -Could you cite a reference?  (I don't believe there's been any evidence for more antimatter than may've comprised the Tunguska fireball, but, even so, why would it have been near some size limit?)

Comment: While fictional, one can actually give fairly rigorous answers to the question. Energy, spectrum, visibility and even ramifications can be analysed using standard physics. The short of it is that antimatter reactions are "dirty" and will accelerate much of the matter to relativistic speeds in all directions where it will not get a chance to react much more, it will be somewhat brighter than extreme AGN outbursts (visible over gigaparsec ranges), but not really affect the universe much. It would be messy.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter):
“Most matter observable from the Earth seems to be made of matter rather than antimatter. If antimatter-dominated regions of space existed, the gamma rays produced in annihilation reactions along the boundary between matter and antimatter regions would be detectable.”

Comment: The [Tunguska](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter_comet#Tunguska_event_of_1908) event was *not* due to antimatter. This is a discredited theory.

Comment: Although this is fictional, the idea of antimatter regions in the universe was proposed as a possible explanation for the matter-antimatter imbalance several decades ago, but rejected due to the lack of the tell-tale 0.511 MeV gamma rays produced when electrons & positrons annihilate. So I don't feel this question *necessarily* needs to be closed as non-mainstream. OTOH, getting 2 galaxies of identical mass to annihilate simultaneously is fairly unrealistic...

Comment: You're asking what would happen our galaxy if it was completely destroyed.  Doesn't this question answer itself ?

Comment: The "physically Einsteinian" (GR- or ECT-based) cosmology that remains the most plausible to me is Poplawski's torsion-based theory, which depends on a scale difference of ^32 between matter & antimatter particle pairs separated (by the outward-propagating event horizon of a gravitationally-collapsing star) and the (MUCH) larger spinning fermions of the star itself, which actually seems (at least, at 1st glance at all the helpful info revealed by other participants) to remain consistent with that evidence, altho any collision would seem to have occurred on an averaged scale above galaxies'.

Comment: I have to clarify that, when I said "any collision" in my previous comment, I wasn't including the contact between the stellar fermions and the newly-separated (materialized) fermions, which would result in a huge acceleration of the latter, as well as a reversal of many of their trajectories that would carry them into the zone where they would've formed a new local (i.e., "causally-separated") universe (perhaps our own), in a process perhaps continuing in our LU's own "black holes".  I've up-voted the question, not in disagreement with G. Smith's remarks, but to discourage its withdrawal.